# Automate a cross-environment db restore in Heroku

Tags: api, heroku

I have two heroku environments and I'd like to copy the latest backup of the Production database to my Development environment.

With the CLI, this is easy:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app Production` --app Development --confirm Development
```

But I'd like to automate this. So I made it a rake task that uses the heroku_api gem. This should allow to call it from the Heroku Scheduler.

```
task :auto_refresh do
  @heroku = Heroku::API.new(...)
  @heroku.post_ps('Development', 'heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app Production` --app Development --confirm Development')
end
```

This does not work. All it does is refresh Development from the latest Development backup.

Any ideas how I can automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'heroku' gem (not 'heroku-api' gem), you can manipulate the list of backups from one app to another

When you install the pgbackups addon, it creates a config variable PGBACKUPS_URL. You'll need to use this value in your Dev app like so:

```
# Get the latest backup
client = Heroku::Client::Pgbackups.new('https://bigmessything@pgbackups.heroku.com/client')
backup = client.get_latest_backup
```

backup['public_url] should contain the URL you want to restore from using the code you have above